# Why won't my function follow my if/else conditions?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K5dsh/

I'm trying to make a simple calculator that evaluates the difference between the numbers its given, and gives an answer based on that. It has two problems:

1.) The answer my script gives is always the result of my 2nd `else if` statement, even if the input matches the conditions before it.

2.) The answer does not change even when there's a new input that should give a different result.

Does anyone see what the problems are? Thank you.

Comment: For one, the high, low, and common variables are only being assigned once.

Comment: Please post the relevant portions of your code directly.

Comment: Here's a cleaned up fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/K5dsh/2/

Comment: Can you be more specific please? I don't understand why that creates a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ivan pointed out, you're never updating the values of `high`, `low` and `common` with the values entered into the textboxes. You should be assigning the values inside the `calculate` function. [See updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K5dsh/4/).

Also, you may want to invest some time into learning a framework like [Knockout.js](http://knockoutjs.com/). It makes data-binding HTML form elements to JavaScript view models incredibly simple.

Comment: I understand now, I didn't realize I had to define them inside the function. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your variables are defined only once. You should change it so that every time your button is clicked, it grabs the new variables. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Vd8n4/

Answer (score 0):

Your values aren't being updated.

Here's how I would go about it.  I'd change your function so that it starts off like this.  That way, every time it is called, it updates the high, low, and common values.

```
function calculate() {
    var high = document.getElementById('highRi').value;
    var low =  document.getElementById('lowRi').value;
    var common =  document.getElementById('comm').value;
```